# Kivy: Getting a fixed-size widget to display in the centre of the window

Tags: python, kivy

I've been pulling my hair out about this for hours. I have a custom widget that subclasses `RelativeLayout`, which needs to be of a fixed size. I want this widget to display in the centre of the window. I will also want other, normal widgets (ie. buttons) to display around it. After spending an entire day getting the thing to centre in the first place, I now find that upon adding a button it resists all my attempts to get it to behave. Please could someone take a look at my .kv file and tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

# This is my fixed-size widget
<DrawableGrid>:
    # Note: this is just an example size to keep things simple
    size: 500, 500
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

# This subclasses BoxLayout    
CustomLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    # I put my DrawableGrid inside an AnchorLayout in the hope that it might
    # behave in some way like the documentation says it does. No such luck.
    # This should be taking up the entire top half of the window.
    AnchorLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        # This anchor_x/anchor_y stuff seemingly does nothing.
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "center"

        # This should be appearing as a red rectangle of size 500x500
        DrawableGrid:
            # This next line was needed to set a custom size in the first place
            size_hint: 0, 0

    # This appears exactly as expected, filling the bottom half of the window.
    Button:
        id: next_button
        text: "Next"
```

So, to reiterate, what I currently want is:

- The window split into two halves horizontally (ie. a top half and a bottom half)
- The top half should contain my custom widget at size 500x500, centered, and nothing else. This should display as a red square.
- The bottom half should contain a button with the text 'Next', filling the entire bottom half.

And what I actually get is this:
[image: Screenshot]
(as you can see, the red square is conspicuously absent)

I have tried a whole number of different ways (some more hacky than others) to get this work, but to no avail. Please can someone advise how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a vertical BoxLayout as your root widget. The first widget in root will be a RelativeLayout and the second will be your button. This will give you the 50/50 split screen. The RelativeLayout will contain your 500x500 widget with a position of (self.parent.width-self.width)/2, (self.parent.height-self.height)/2

Note: in the following code example, I use 100x100 as the widget since 500x500 would not fit on my screen.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


kv = """
<Test>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    RelativeLayout:
        GridLayout:
            pos: (self.parent.width-self.width)/2, (self.parent.height-self.height)/2
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 100
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

    Button:
        text: "Next"
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class Test(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` positions all children relative to the layout's position. This includes all drawing instructions - because that's all children really are. All of a layout's children are drawn on the `canvas`, so the positions used within the `canvas` must be relative to the layout itself! So when you say in `canvas` to draw the rectangle at `self.pos`, that position is translated just like any other child (in other words, the rectangle is drawn at `self.pos + self.pos`). If you change the rectangle pos to `0, 0` then it will draw as you expect.

To help explain, here is the default style for `RelativeLayout` (from `kivy/data/style.kv`):

```
<RelativeLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Translate:
            xy: self.pos
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
```

Anything you put in `canvas` happens between `canvas.before` and `canvas.after`.